# Convert .m4p to non-DRM format (mp3, ogg)

Tags: linux, mp3, quicktime, drm, ogg

Do you know how to convert a .m4p file (DRM quicktime) to mp3 or ogg without using expensive software (AKA with scripting) and possibly on Linux?

Comment: Can you play the file with mplayer? If so, you can always use mencoder to save it to some other format.

Comment: If it is DRM, I think it might be illegal (depends on the country) to use as anything else (Although it is probably technically posible).

Comment: **@kuba** are you 6?

**@all** It's LEGAL in my country to remove DRM from stuff you buy, and you can even buy software that does that.
 
Unfortunately mplayer can't play m4p (same for faad). Those are the first options I checked myself.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good method for decrypting encrypted DRM quicktime files in linux.  You can probably play them with quicktime via wine (just a guess), but to save them to a different format would probably be difficult.  (though thinking out loud, I wonder if it be possible to have an alsa plugin that dumps every stream of audio it gets to a file as well?)